Facing unexpected shutdown issue on Ubuntu 20.04 Server
"We're experiencing unexpected shutdowns on a machine running Ubuntu 20.04 with an NVIDIA 4090 GPU. The system uses NVIDIA drivers NVIDIA-SMI 535.171.04 and kernel version 5.15.0-1052-intel-iotg. The machine works fine for a while but then shuts down unexpectedly, and it doesn't restart automatically. We've noticed ACPI errors and thermal errors in the logs."
Please look at the error logs below:
 ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    0.993513] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    3.596622] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210730/nsarguments-61)
[    3.778368] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[    3.778391] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[    3.778415] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    3.778537] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [\_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[    3.778556] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)"
ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    3.568606] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel


After the system comes up again, the terminal command sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex will show the system logs leading up to the crash /shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the -b -1 option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do sudo journalctl  --list-boots, read man journalctl. For more journalctl help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).
